# Atom styling for keyword "this"

Tags: this, atom-editor

Is it possible to give the keyword `this` custom styles in your Atom stylesheet? E.g. make it bold, so it stands out more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by editing your `styles.less` file.

Assuming you're interested in assigning `this` from javascript to be bold, the following snippet will handle your question:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {

    .variable.language.js {
        font-weight: 800;
    }

}
```

The classes for the specific elements you are trying to style can be found easily by opening up Developer Tools (View > Developer > Toggle Developer Tools), clicking the magnifying glass located on the top-left of the dev-tools panel, and then hovering over the word(s) you are interested in styling.

See [here](https://atom.io/docs/v1.2.4/upgrading-to-1-0-apis-upgrading-your-syntax-theme) for more information.